# Validation Framework in C++

Tags: c++, validation, frameworks

Both Java and .Net seem to have a wealth of object validation frameworks (e.g. [Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/index.html), [XWork](http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/wikidocs/Validation%20Framework.html), etc.), but I've been unable to find anything similar for C++. Has anyone come across something like this, or do people typically roll their own?

Comment: Hi! Could you give a more context what're you looking for? Should it be a validation framework for testing, or for production use? Should it compose some sort of report describing the problem? It would be also better if you provide some sort of example of code at the input, and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

In 2020 there is [cpp-validator](https://github.com/evgeniums/cpp-validator) library.

This is a C++14/C++17 header-only library that can be used to validate:

- plain variables;
- properties of objects, where a property can be accessed either as object's variable or object's getter method;
- contents and properties of containers;
- nested containers and objects.

Basic usage of the library includes two steps:

- first, define a validator using almost declarative syntax;
- then, apply the validator to data that must be validated and check the results.

See example below.

```cpp
// define validator
auto string_validator=validator(
  value(gte,"sample string"),
  size(lt,15)
);

// validate variable
std::string var="sample";
error_report err;
validate(var,string_validator,err);
if (err)
{
   std::cerr << err.message() << std::endl;
   /* prints:
      must be greater than or equal to "sample string"
   */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some GUI frameworks have validators.
Check out [wxWidgets Validators](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_validatoroverview.html#validatoroverview)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Qt has something similar. The difference is that GUI framework validators evaluate the value in the GUI controls, while I want validation of my data objects. In other words, I need validation of my data model, not my presentation.